# Transforming numbers to \alph numbers

Tags: macros, numbering

Is it possible to have a simple command `\makeAlph` which would do the following :

- return `a` when it receives `1`
- return `b` when it receives `2`
- etc.
- return nothing (or whatever ; actually that's not important for me) in the other cases
  ?

Thank you.

PS : I know how to do it with `counters` but this is not what I want.

Comment: What do you mean with “return `` in the other cases”?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel it's a typo, sorry.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}%
\newcommand*\makeAlph[1]{\symbol{\numexpr96+#1}}
\begin{document}

\makeAlph{10}
\makeAlph{22}

This is the first letter of the alphabet : \makeAlph{1}

\end{document}
```

if you want to allow all numbers then use:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\newcommand*\makeAlph[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<1\else% do nothing if < 1
    \ifnum#1>26 a\makeAlph{\numexpr#1-26}% start loop
    \else\symbol{\numexpr96+#1}\fi\fi}
\begin{document}

This is the first letter of the alphabet : \makeAlph{1}

\makeAlph{10}  \makeAlph{44}
\makeAlph{-3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ``\symbol{\numexpr`a-1+#1}`` may be even clearer.

Comment: Does it work when `#1<1` or `#1>26`?

Comment: @mbork: No. It can't handle such thinks.

Comment: @mbork: that can easily be extended to get something like aaab, see my edit

Comment: @Herbert: If you want to provide a bigger range you can use: `\newcommand*\makeAlph[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<1\else
    \ifnum#1>26 
      \count0=#1
      \divide\count0 by 26%    
      \makeAlph{\the\count0}%
      \makeAlph{\numexpr(#1-26*\the\count0)}%
    \else\symbol{\numexpr96+#1}\fi\fi}`

Answer (score 20):

The LaTeX kernel already has it:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makeAlph}[1]{\@alph{#1}}
\makeatother
```

However this returns an error if the argument is greater than 26. If you want that nothing is returned for an out of range input, just copy the definition of `\@alph` without the error message:

```
\newcommand{\makeAlph[1]{%
  \ifcase #1\or a\or b\or c\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or
    i\or j\or k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or q\or r\or
    s\or t\or u\or v\or w\or x\or y\or z\fi}
```

If you want to return `?` for the out of range cases,

```
\newcommand{\makeAlph[1]{%
  \ifcase #1?\or a\or b\or c\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or
    i\or j\or k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or q\or r\or
    s\or t\or u\or v\or w\or x\or y\or z\else ?\fi}
```

The advantage over the approaches shown in other answers is that the last two definitions use only fully expandable functions. Also `\int_to_alph:n` is fully expandable, of course.

Comment: Dear @egreg, what does it mean `fully expandable` ?

Comment: @Colas That you can use the last version of `\makeAlph` in `\edef` or `\write`. Not so important, perhaps, in this application, but in many situations it's crucial.

Answer (score 15):

There is also a nice expl3 implementation

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \makealph { m }
 {
  \int_to_alph:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\makealph{1}

\makealph{5}

\makealph{35}

\end{document}
```

As pointed out the definition of `\makealph` should be done by `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` so that it can be used in an expansion context.

If you want use a LaTeX2e solution you can use the package [`alphalph`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/alphalph):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\newcounter{mycounter}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{mycounter}{2}
\alph{mycounter}

\setcounter{mycounter}{35}

\alphalph{\value{mycounter}}

\alphalph{17}
\end{document}
```

Please note that the package `alphalph` requires a numerical input and not a counter.

Comment: About the command : `alph{}`. 
I would like to have a command `makeAlph` that I can use in my text, to do something like : 
`This is the first letter of the alphabet : \makeAlph{1}`.

Comment: I'd use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`, so that `\makealph` can be used in an expansion context.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I've never seen such things... (expl3) What is it ? Is it a huge great new thing ?

Comment: @Colas: Yes it's a huge and of course great thing ;-)