# How to redefine definition theoremstyle to use a letter instead of a number

Tags: theorems

I need to redefine the theorem style. Is it possible to change the numbers to letters?

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\begin{problem}
fff
\end{problem}
\begin{problem}
ccc
\end{problem}
```

I need to do this:

> Problem A. fff
>
> Problem B. ccc

instead of using numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the representation for the counter, in this case, `problem` is the counter, and `\theproblem` holds the representation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition} 
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\renewcommand\theproblem{\Alph{problem}}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
test
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, be careful to reset the counter after maximum 26 problems.

Comment: @user32680: With this standard method you are limited to 26 problems ;-). See here for a solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118283/transforming-numbers-to-alph-numbers

Comment: And if I want to redefine proof environment? When I begin, I want to have the text "Solution". Is it possible?

Comment: @user32680 Use `\renewcommand\proofname{Solution}` or define a new theorem-like structure giving you the required settings.

Comment: I really thank you a lot! Thank you for your time!