# I want to create a command like "\mês" which returns the atual month in portuguese, like "Agosto"

Tags: macros, date

I want to create a command like "\mês" which returns the atual month in portuguese, like "Agosto".

I'm usually using the command \the\year to show the year, and the \date returns all the date "20/08/2021" and the \month return just the number. I need to create a command to return the month in portuguese.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't<sup>1</sup> have a macro called `\mês`, with an accented letter, so here's a `\mes` macro:

```latex
\newcommand\mes{\ifcase\month
  \or Janeiro\or Fevereiro\or Março\or Abril\or Maio\or Junho\or
  Julho\or Agosto\or Setembro\or Outubro\or Novembro\or Dezembro\fi}
```

It takes the value of `\month` and branches to one of twelve cases (there's an explanation about the syntax of `\ifcase` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/595046/134574)), and writes the respective month.

---

[1]: Terms and conditions may apply:  you can have a macro called `\mês` if you are using an Unicode engine like XeTeX or LuaTeX, or if you create the control sequence indirectly with `\csname mês\endcsname`, but it's usually better to stick to ASCII for macro names.

Comment: Perfect! It was exactly what i was needing. Thank you very much!